# In python, can a whole file be just a variable?

Tags: python, file, variables

I saw a javascript project had defined very large variables in their own files named the same as the variable eg the large array named marker was in a file called marker.js. Conveniently the variable could be used directly with any import or so, directly acessing it as though it were in the same file.

Now I have large variables in a python project and I wonder if I could do something similar ie refactor out the very large list to a file of its own or is it not possible / not a good idea?

Thank you

**Update**
My "very large variable" is basically the most detailed geography I can:

```
location_map_br = {
    1: {
        'name': 'São Paulo'.decode('utf-8'),
        'lat': -23.55,
        'long': -46.64,
        'radius': 294200,
        },
    2: {
        'name': 'Rio De Janeiro',
        'lat': -22.90,
        'long': -43.21,
        'radius': 294200,
        },
```

...

The code is alright, it just needs structuring so that large variables get out of the way of application logic.

Comment: What do you mean by a "large variable"?

Comment: Example http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/data.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly good idea, especially if these values are defined constants or lookup tables.

Here is an excerpt of a lookup table from some code where I work (open sourced, so I'm not giving away any secrets):

```
DCOM_ERROR_CONSTANTS = {
    1726:'RPC_S_CALL_FAILED',
    0:'WBEM_NO_ERROR',
    0x40001:'WBEM_S_ALREADY_EXISTS',
    0x40002:'WBEM_S_RESET_TO_DEFAULT',
    0x40003:'WBEM_S_DIFFERENT',
    0x40004:'WBEM_S_TIMEDOUT',
    0x40005:'WBEM_S_NO_MORE_DATA',
    0x40006:'WBEM_S_OPERATION_CANCELLED',
    0x40007:'WBEM_S_PENDING',
    0x40008:'WBEM_S_DUPLICATE_OBJECTS',
    0x40009:'WBEM_S_ACCESS_DENIED',
    0x40010:'WBEM_S_PARTIAL_RESULTS',
    0x40011:'WBEM_S_NO_POSTHOOK',
    0x40012:'WBEM_S_POSTHOOK_WITH_BOTH',
    0x40013:'WBEM_S_POSTHOOK_WITH_NEW',
    0x40014:'WBEM_S_POSTHOOK_WITH_STATUS',
    0x40015:'WBEM_S_POSTHOOK_WITH_OLD',
    0x40016:'WBEM_S_REDO_PREHOOK_WITH_ORIGINAL_OBJECT',
    0x40017:'WBEM_S_SOURCE_NOT_AVAILABLE',
    0x80041001:'WBEM_E_FAILED',
    0x80041002:'WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND',
    0x80041003:'WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED',
    0x80041004:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_FAILURE',
    0x80041005:'WBEM_E_TYPE_MISMATCH',
    0x80041006:'WBEM_E_OUT_OF_MEMORY',
    0x80041007:'WBEM_E_INVALID_CONTEXT',
    0x80041008:'WBEM_E_INVALID_PARAMETER',
    0x80041009:'WBEM_E_NOT_AVAILABLE',
    0x8004100A:'WBEM_E_CRITICAL_ERROR',
    0x8004100B:'WBEM_E_INVALID_STREAM',
    0x8004100C:'WBEM_E_NOT_SUPPORTED',
    0x8004100D:'WBEM_E_INVALID_SUPERCLASS',
    0x8004100E:'WBEM_E_INVALID_NAMESPACE',
    0x8004100F:'WBEM_E_INVALID_OBJECT',
    0x80041010:'WBEM_E_INVALID_CLASS',
    0x80041011:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_NOT_FOUND',
    0x80041012:'WBEM_E_INVALID_PROVIDER_REGISTRATION',
    0x80041013:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_LOAD_FAILURE',
    0x80041014:'WBEM_E_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE',
    0x80041015:'WBEM_E_TRANSPORT_FAILURE',
    0x80041016:'WBEM_E_INVALID_OPERATION',
    0x80041017:'WBEM_E_INVALID_QUERY',
    0x80041018:'WBEM_E_INVALID_QUERY_TYPE',
    0x80041019:'WBEM_E_ALREADY_EXISTS',
    0x8004101A:'WBEM_E_OVERRIDE_NOT_ALLOWED',
    0x8004101B:'WBEM_E_PROPAGATED_QUALIFIER',
    0x8004101C:'WBEM_E_PROPAGATED_PROPERTY',
    0x8004101D:'WBEM_E_UNEXPECTED',
    0x8004101E:'WBEM_E_ILLEGAL_OPERATION',
    0x8004101F:'WBEM_E_CANNOT_BE_KEY',
    0x80041020:'WBEM_E_INCOMPLETE_CLASS',
    0x80041021:'WBEM_E_INVALID_SYNTAX',
    0x80041022:'WBEM_E_NONDECORATED_OBJECT',
    0x80041023:'WBEM_E_READ_ONLY',
    0x80041024:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_NOT_CAPABLE',
    0x80041025:'WBEM_E_CLASS_HAS_CHILDREN',
    0x80041026:'WBEM_E_CLASS_HAS_INSTANCES',
    0x80041027:'WBEM_E_QUERY_NOT_IMPLEMENTED',
    0x80041028:'WBEM_E_ILLEGAL_NULL',
    0x80041029:'WBEM_E_INVALID_QUALIFIER_TYPE',
    0x8004102A:'WBEM_E_INVALID_PROPERTY_TYPE',
    0x8004102B:'WBEM_E_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE',
    0x8004102C:'WBEM_E_CANNOT_BE_SINGLETON',
    0x8004102D:'WBEM_E_INVALID_CIM_TYPE',
    0x8004102E:'WBEM_E_INVALID_METHOD',
    0x8004102F:'WBEM_E_INVALID_METHOD_PARAMETERS',
    0x80041030:'WBEM_E_SYSTEM_PROPERTY',
    0x80041031:'WBEM_E_INVALID_PROPERTY',
    0x80041032:'WBEM_E_CALL_CANCELLED',
    0x80041033:'WBEM_E_SHUTTING_DOWN',
    0x80041034:'WBEM_E_PROPAGATED_METHOD',
    0x80041035:'WBEM_E_UNSUPPORTED_PARAMETER',
    0x80041036:'WBEM_E_MISSING_PARAMETER_ID',
    0x80041037:'WBEM_E_INVALID_PARAMETER_ID',
    0x80041038:'WBEM_E_NONCONSECUTIVE_PARAMETER_IDS',
    0x80041039:'WBEM_E_PARAMETER_ID_ON_RETVAL',
    0x8004103A:'WBEM_E_INVALID_OBJECT_PATH',
    0x8004103B:'WBEM_E_OUT_OF_DISK_SPACE',
    0x8004103C:'WBEM_E_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL',
    0x8004103D:'WBEM_E_UNSUPPORTED_PUT_EXTENSION',
    0x8004103E:'WBEM_E_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE',
    0x8004103F:'WBEM_E_UNKNOWN_PACKET_TYPE',
    0x80041040:'WBEM_E_MARSHAL_VERSION_MISMATCH',
    0x80041041:'WBEM_E_MARSHAL_INVALID_SIGNATURE',
    0x80041042:'WBEM_E_INVALID_QUALIFIER',
    0x80041043:'WBEM_E_INVALID_DUPLICATE_PARAMETER',
    0x80041044:'WBEM_E_TOO_MUCH_DATA',
    0x80041045:'WBEM_E_SERVER_TOO_BUSY',
    0x80041046:'WBEM_E_INVALID_FLAVOR',
    0x80041047:'WBEM_E_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE',
    0x80041048:'WBEM_E_UNSUPPORTED_CLASS_UPDATE',
    0x80041049:'WBEM_E_CANNOT_CHANGE_KEY_INHERITANCE',
    0x80041050:'WBEM_E_CANNOT_CHANGE_INDEX_INHERITANCE',
    0x80041051:'WBEM_E_TOO_MANY_PROPERTIES',
    0x80041052:'WBEM_E_UPDATE_TYPE_MISMATCH',
    0x80041053:'WBEM_E_UPDATE_OVERRIDE_NOT_ALLOWED',
    0x80041054:'WBEM_E_UPDATE_PROPAGATED_METHOD',
    0x80041055:'WBEM_E_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED',
    0x80041056:'WBEM_E_METHOD_DISABLED',
    0x80041057:'WBEM_E_REFRESHER_BUSY',
    0x80041058:'WBEM_E_UNPARSABLE_QUERY',
    0x80041059:'WBEM_E_NOT_EVENT_CLASS',
    0x8004105A:'WBEM_E_MISSING_GROUP_WITHIN',
    0x8004105B:'WBEM_E_MISSING_AGGREGATION_LIST',
    0x8004105C:'WBEM_E_PROPERTY_NOT_AN_OBJECT',
    0x8004105D:'WBEM_E_AGGREGATING_BY_OBJECT',
    0x8004105F:'WBEM_E_UNINTERPRETABLE_PROVIDER_QUERY',
    0x80041060:'WBEM_E_BACKUP_RESTORE_WINMGMT_RUNNING',
    0x80041061:'WBEM_E_QUEUE_OVERFLOW',
    0x80041062:'WBEM_E_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD',
    0x80041063:'WBEM_E_INVALID_OPERATOR',
    0x80041064:'WBEM_E_LOCAL_CREDENTIALS',
    0x80041065:'WBEM_E_CANNOT_BE_ABSTRACT',
    0x80041066:'WBEM_E_AMENDED_OBJECT',
    0x80041067:'WBEM_E_CLIENT_TOO_SLOW',
    0x80041068:'WBEM_E_NULL_SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR',
    0x80041069:'WBEM_E_TIMED_OUT',
    0x8004106A:'WBEM_E_INVALID_ASSOCIATION',
    0x8004106B:'WBEM_E_AMBIGUOUS_OPERATION',
    0x8004106C:'WBEM_E_QUOTA_VIOLATION',
    0x8004106D:'WBEM_E_RESERVED_001',
    0x8004106E:'WBEM_E_RESERVED_002',
    0x8004106F:'WBEM_E_UNSUPPORTED_LOCALE',
    0x80041070:'WBEM_E_HANDLE_OUT_OF_DATE',
    0x80041071:'WBEM_E_CONNECTION_FAILED',
    0x80041072:'WBEM_E_INVALID_HANDLE_REQUEST',
    0x80041073:'WBEM_E_PROPERTY_NAME_TOO_WIDE',
    0x80041074:'WBEM_E_CLASS_NAME_TOO_WIDE',
    0x80041075:'WBEM_E_METHOD_NAME_TOO_WIDE',
    0x80041076:'WBEM_E_QUALIFIER_NAME_TOO_WIDE',
    0x80041077:'WBEM_E_RERUN_COMMAND',
    0x80041078:'WBEM_E_DATABASE_VER_MISMATCH',
    0x80041079:'WBEM_E_VETO_DELETE',
    0x8004107A:'WBEM_E_VETO_PUT',
    0x80041080:'WBEM_E_INVALID_LOCALE',
    0x80041081:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_SUSPENDED',
    0x80041082:'WBEM_E_SYNCHRONIZATION_REQUIRED',
    0x80041083:'WBEM_E_NO_SCHEMA',
    0x80041084:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_ALREADY_REGISTERED',
    0x80041085:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_NOT_REGISTERED',
    0x80041086:'WBEM_E_FATAL_TRANSPORT_ERROR',
    0x80041087:'WBEM_E_ENCRYPTED_CONNECTION_REQUIRED',
    0x80041088:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_TIMED_OUT',
    0x80041089:'WBEM_E_NO_KEY',
    0x8004108a:'WBEM_E_PROVIDER_DISABLED',
    # not dcom, but frequently seen
    0x000006be: 'OPERATION_COULD_NOT_BE_COMPLETED',
}
```

Instead of cluttering up my code, this large conversion table is kept in a separate file and just imported as needed.

```
from library import DCOM_ERROR_CONSTANTS
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! I now just wonder what is a file and what is a module. I named the file and the variable the same thing and got into problem converting my dictionary to a list when python thinks that my dictionary is a module. Anyway I can solve this problem many different ways. The part of my code that didn't comply was ` `location_map_india = sorted(location_map_india.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['name'])`

Answer (score 3):

I am not totally sure about your question, but isn't that what [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) are for?

---

Example: I have some zipcode logic and a large python data structure containing actual zipcodes:

```
zipproj/zipcodelogic.py
zipproj/zipcodes.py
```

where `zipcodes.py` would look like

```
zipcodes = [
    ('10304', 'Richmond County, NY'),
    ... 
    # and over 42,000 more zipcodes
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#Statistics
    ...
]
```

In `zipcodelogic.py` you would simple `import zipcodes` (and the handle to the list would be `zipcodes.zipcodes`).

On other occasions one might also look into object serialization, e.g. via [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html), [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) or [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Comment: Great! What I want seems possible. I update the question with my actual variable now

Comment: @miku: I have a question. The `zipcodes` list from `zipcodes.py`, after you import it in `zipcodelogic.py` using `import zipcodes` statement, is accessible as `zipcodes.zipcodes` - am I right? If so, then maybe it is worth mentioning that the actual variable is named `zipcodes.zipcodes` in the given example, unless imported using `from zipcodes import zipcodes` statement?

Comment: @Tadeck, yes that's correct + added a short note in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understand your requirements completely...

Furthermore I don't know if it's just a language problem, but **you referred to your values as *variables* not as *constants***, so I wonder if modules are really what you want [in python there are - strictly speaking - no real *constants*. To the purposes of this answer I am considering as "constants" those variables whose value doesn't change and it is assign in the source code, rather than at runtime].

However: in python, **the standard way to get persistence of *variables*** (= values assigned at runtime) **is via the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) and the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) modules**. On the other hand, modules are the standard way to import constants, but you have to be careful on how you use them, in order to prevent namespace pollution.

For example, a standard way to load constant looks like:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

This works but if in your module you had other imports (if in `pygame.locals` you wrote `from numpy import sum`, for example) you will end up - in the file when you imported the `locals` - with `sum` being defined as `numpy.sum` rather than the standard `sum` built-in function... This is referred to as **"namespace pollution"**.

To avoid this, but still being able to import the `locals` in your source code, you can define the module variable `__all__` that whitelists the objects that will be imported when the module is imported with the star (`*`) operator.

HTH!

Comment: I added a "variable" and yes, it is a constant as you can now inspect.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's a good idea, and as Miku and Paul have already explained it's possible. There is another options that consists in store that data in a csv file or xml, but I think it's only worth doing it if some other program (not writen in python) has to access directly to that data.